# What can I use to find the unresponsive program and it's id?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

If program crashes , How can I find the id of this program? . I do not the name of the unresponsive program.

Answer (score 6):

There are a several ways ways.

First, download and run 'htop' from inside a terminal. You can sort processes by CPU usage - if you have a process not responding, often these will be chugging CPU like none other.

Alternately, try running 'ps -A' in a terminal. This will give you a list of processes, and if you have a general idea of what the process is, you can then see its PID and thus kill it.

**Finally, and probably most usefully**, if the unresponsive program is a graphical program, and you just want to kill it rather than find outs its PID, run 'xkill' from the alt-f2 popup. This will turn your cursor into a skull and crossbones, and if you just click the unresponsive window it will be killed instantly.

Comment: why not just hack `top` into the terminal. it is installed on every unix and lists the pid.

Comment: many people don't know how to use top, or find it unpleasant or scary. 'htop' is similar, except much easier to navigate. Although I agree, if you're up to it, 'top' is a good bet as well

Answer (score 0):

you can use task manager.  When you pull it up, right click on the unresponsive program and then click "go to process" Then by clicking "view" then "Select Columns" you can add the column PID.  Then determine the PID from that.

Comment: If you check the tags of the question, he's asking how to do this in Linux/Unix, and ideally from the command-line. There isn't really a "standard" graphical task manager in Linux/Unix. Which task manager are you referencing?

Comment: Wow didn't check tags.  I assumed he was in windows.